# What does this mean: “Also es gibt in Berlin auch Museen, die ich mag. Und es gibt ja dich!“

Tags: meaning, pronoun, colloquial, informal

What does this sentence mean?

Context: my ex partner and I started talking to each other again. He lives in another city and I live in Berlin. He said he wants to visit Berlin and said this sentence (he had previously mentioned that museums in the city he lives in are better than in Berlin)

I’m actually confused about the “und es gibt ja dich”- part.
Does it mean the fact that I live in Berlin is something that he likes?

Or what would you think?

Comment: You should ask him what it means.

Answer (score 6):

In this context, "Und es gibt ja dich" is most probably a shortened form of "Und es gibt in Berlin ja dich."

Note that he is mentioning things that are a motivation for him to travel to Berlin - namely some museums that are locatad in Berlin and that he likes. The existence of these museums is a motivation to him to visit Berlin.

And then, he lists another motivation - your existence. The fact that you exist (in Berlin, even though that is not explicitly mentioned here) is another motivation for him to come there.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say without more context whether he thinks "I like that you live in Berlin." (and not anywhere else).

He stated that he likes *some* museums that exist in Berlin *and* you. I believe where you live wasn't really the thing he wanted to point out, but much more that he likes you.
If he travels to Berlin, he won't only do so for the museum.